# Web scraping using selenium, multiprocessing, InstagramBot

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium, instagram

An Instagram Bot which downloads the posts from profile

I have to mention my previous posts:

1. [Instagram scraper Posts (Videos and Photos)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238713/instagram-scraper-posts-videos-and-photos])
2. [Scraping Instagram with selenium, extract URLs, download posts](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238902/scraping-instagram-with-selenium-extract-urls-download-posts)

My code:

````
import requests
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import urllib.parse
import argparse
import re
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

LINKS = []
PICTURES = []
VIDEO = []
chromedriver_path = None


def check_availability(link, session_base):
    """
    This function checks the availability of profile and the status code
    :param session_base: The requests session
    :param link:  link that searching for and includes the profile name
    :return: raise Exception if <privacy> is True and <followed_by_viewer> is False
    """
    search = session_base.get(urllib.parse.urljoin(link, "?__a=1"))
    search.raise_for_status()

    load_and_check = search.json()
    privacy = load_and_check.get("graphql").get("user").get("is_private")
    followed_by_viewer = load_and_check.get("graphql").get("user").get("followed_by_viewer")
    if privacy and not followed_by_viewer:
        raise Exception("[!] Account is private")


def fetch_url(url, session_base):
    """
    This function extracts images and videos
    :param session_base: The requests session
    :param url: Taking the url of array LINKS
    """
    logging_page_id = session_base.get(url.split()[0]).json()
    try:
        """Taking Gallery Photos or Videos"""
        for log_pages in logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_sidecar_to_children']['edges']:
            video = log_pages.get("node").get("is_video")
            if video:
                video_url = log_pages.get("node").get("video_url")
                VIDEO.append(video_url)
            else:
                image = log_pages.get("node").get("display_url")
                PICTURES.append(image)

    except KeyError:
        """Unique photo or Video"""
        image = logging_page_id.get('graphql').get('shortcode_media').get('display_url')
        PICTURES.append(image)

        if logging_page_id.get('graphql').get('shortcode_media').get("is_video"):
            videos = logging_page_id.get('graphql').get('shortcode_media').get("video_url")
            VIDEO.append(videos)


class InstagramPV:

    def __init__(self, username, password, folder, search_name):
        """

        :param username: username
        :param password: password
        :param folder: folder name
        :param search_name: the name what will search
        """
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.folder = folder
        self.HttpBase = requests.Session()

        """To avoid any errors, with regex find the url and taking the name <search_name>"""
        find_name = "".join(re.findall(r"(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", search_name))
        if find_name.startswith("https"):
            self.search_name = urllib.parse.urlparse(find_name).path.split("/")[1]
        else:
            self.search_name = search_name

        if chromedriver_path is not None:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
        else:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def control(self):
        """
        Create the folder name and raises an error if already exists
        """
        if not os.path.exists(self.folder):
            os.mkdir(self.folder)
        else:
            raise FileExistsError("[*] Already Exists This Folder")

    def login(self):
        """Login To Instagram"""
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login")
        time.sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)
        submit = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('form')
        submit.submit()
        time.sleep(3)

        """Check For Invalid Credentials"""
        try:
            var_error = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("eiCW-").text
            raise ValueError("[!] Invalid Credentials")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try:
            """Close Notifications"""
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]').click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        time.sleep(2)
        """Taking Cookies and update the self.HttpBase"""
        cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()

        for cookie in cookies:
            c = {cookie["name"]: cookie["value"]}
            self.HttpBase.cookies.update(c)

        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/{name}/".format(name=self.search_name))

        """Checking for availability"""
        check_availability("https://www.instagram.com/{name}/".format(name=self.search_name), self.HttpBase)

        return self.scroll_down()

    def _get_href(self):
        elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
        for elem in elements:
            urls = elem.get_attribute("href")
            if "p" in urls.split("/"):
                LINKS.append(urls)

    def scroll_down(self):
        """Taking hrefs while scrolling down"""
        end_scroll = []
        while True:
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(2)
            self._get_href()
            time.sleep(2)
            new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            end_scroll.append(new_height)
            if end_scroll.count(end_scroll[-1]) > 4:
                self.extraction_url()
                break

    def extraction_url(self):
        """Gathering Images and Videos Using ThreadPoolExecutor and pass to function <fetch_url> """
        links = list(set(LINKS))
        print("[!] Ready for video - images".title())
        print(f"[*] extracting {len(links)} posts , please wait...".title())

        new_links = [urllib.parse.urljoin(link, "?__a=1") for link in links]
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
            [executor.submit(fetch_url, link, self.HttpBase) for link in new_links]

    def _download_video(self, new_videos):
        """
        Saving the content of video in the file
        """
        number, link = new_videos
        with open(os.path.join(self.folder, f"Video{number}.mp4"), "wb") as f:
            content_of_video = InstagramPV.content_of_url(link)
            f.write(content_of_video)

    def _images_download(self, new_pictures):
        """Saving the content of picture in the file"""
        number, link = new_pictures
        with open(os.path.join(self.folder, f"Image{number}.jpg"), "wb") as f:
            content_of_picture = InstagramPV.content_of_url(link)
            f.write(content_of_picture)

    def downloading_video_images(self):
        """Using multiprocessing for Saving Images and Videos"""
        print("[*] ready for saving images and videos!".title())
        new_pictures = list(set(PICTURES))
        new_videos = list(set(VIDEO))
        picture_data = [i for i in enumerate(new_pictures)]
        video_data = [i for i in enumerate(new_videos)]
        pool = Pool(8)
        pool.map(self._images_download, picture_data)
        pool.map(self._download_video, video_data)
        print("[+] Done")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.HttpBase.close()
        self.driver.close()

    @staticmethod
    def content_of_url(url):
        req = requests.get(url)
        return req.content


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-u", "--username", help='Username or your email of your account', action="store",
                        required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--password", help='Password of your account', action="store", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--filename", help='Filename for storing data', action="store", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-n", "--name", help='Name to search', action="store", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with InstagramPV(args.username, args.password, args.filename, args.name) as pv:
        pv.control()
        pv.login()
        pv.downloading_video_images()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Requests makes things easy

```
session_base.get(urllib.parse.urljoin(link, "?__a=1"))
```

should be

```
session_base.get(link, params={__a: 1})
```

### Exception types

```
    raise Exception("[!] Account is private")
```

The use of the base `Exception` should be replaced by a custom exception of yours. They're easy to make, and using them makes it so that upstream code can more meaningfully handle exceptions.

### Some things need to exist

In these two cases:

```
            video_url = log_pages.get("node").get("video_url")
            VIDEO.append(video_url)


            image = log_pages.get("node").get("display_url")
            PICTURES.append(image)
```

the dictionary value is mandatory, so you shouldn't `get` it; you should use regular bracket indexing. This will allow failures to be caught earlier, instead of leaking `None` into your data.

### Nomenclature

```
self.HttpBase = requests.Session()
```

Member variables should be lower_snake_case, i.e. `http_base`.

### Don't repeat yourself

```
"https://www.instagram.com/{name}/".format(name=self.search_name)
```

should be put in a temporary variable.

### Packed-tuple argument?

This:

```
def _images_download(self, new_pictures):
    number, link = new_pictures
```

is <strike>a little odd</strike> probably necessary due to your use of `map`, so never mind.

### List creation

```
[i for i in enumerate(new_pictures)]
```

should just be

```
list(enumerate(new_pictures))
```

but since you are only iterating through it once, don't even materialize it to a list; simply leave it as

```
picture_data = enumerate(new_pictures)
```

### Globals

These:

```
LINKS = []
PICTURES = []
VIDEO = []
```

are a problem. They're assigned in global scope, and then both written to and read from a class instance. The easy, and vaguely correct, thing to do is to move all of them to members of `InstagramPV`. `fetch_url` would then need to either:

1. return new video and picture lists; or
2. move to being a method on `InstagramPV` and populate the members there.

I think I'd vote for the second, although this is bordering on making an uber-class without meaningful separation. One way to split this up is to make a class for Instagram data (links, pictures, videos) and a class for Instagram scraping (session, authentication, etc.); but I could be convinced that there are other sensible approaches.

### Session use

Why isn't this:

```
@staticmethod
def content_of_url(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    return req.content
```

using your session? It's surprising that it does the right thing without a cookie jar.

Comment: I owe you many thanks and i will update my post to tell you how much i appreciate you and the community. _but I could be convinced that there are other sensible approaches_ . Do you mean to change all my code and try to find a different way? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Put another way: once this round of review is over and you have a large(r) `InstagramPV` class, that means the obvious problems have largely been addressed, and more abstract problems would need to be approached, in this case object-oriented structure. I'd not worry about that yet.

Comment: First of all @Reinderien i thank you. Second , i promise that i will not stop until i will "hear" "well done" from you :). I know that it will be very difficult, but give me a chance to impress you with my progress. It's a challenge for me. My new [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239074/fixing-code-instagram-bot-selenium-web-scraping)

Comment: Great attitude :)

Comment: Packed-tuple argument edited - I don't think you can easily escape the need for a single tuple.