# Instagram Bot, selenium, web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium, instagram

I made some changes in my code from [the previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238969/web-scraping-using-selenium-multiprocessing-instagrambot).

The changes that I made:

- I put all the functions to the class
- All the global arrays I moved them to class too
- Created `PrivateException`
- I made `property` for `search_name`

I could do it with a different approach but I decided to do it step by step.

My idea was:

To create class inheritance with parent class `instagramData` and there to create `classmethods` the functions `check_availability(cls, session, url)`,  `login(cls, username, password, session, url)` and `fetch_url(cls, session, url)` which I can call to the child class `InstagramPv` and doing the rest (extraction links, download and save) but I stayed in the first plan.

First approach

```
import requests
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import urllib.parse
import re
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

chromedriver_path = None


class PrivateException(Exception):
    pass


class InstagramPV:

    def __init__(self, username, password, folder, search_name):
        """

        :param username: username
        :param password: password
        :param folder: folder name
        :param search_name: the name what will search
        """
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.folder = folder
        self.http_base = requests.Session()
        self._search_name = search_name
        self.links = []
        self.pictures = []
        self.videos = []
        self.url = "https://www.instagram.com/{name}/"
        if chromedriver_path is not None:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
        else:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    @property
    def name(self):
        """To avoid any errors, with regex find the url and taking the name <search_name>"""
        find_name = "".join(re.findall(r"(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", self._search_name))
        if find_name.startswith("https"):
            self._search_name = urllib.parse.urlparse(find_name).path.split("/")[1]
            return self._search_name
        else:
            return self._search_name

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def check_availability(self):

        search = self.http_base.get(self.url.format(name=self.name), params={"__a": 1})
        search.raise_for_status()

        load_and_check = search.json()
        privacy = load_and_check.get("graphql").get("user").get("is_private")
        followed_by_viewer = load_and_check.get("graphql").get("user").get("followed_by_viewer")
        if privacy and not followed_by_viewer:
            raise PrivateException("[!] Account is private")

    def control(self):
        """
        Create the folder name and raises an error if already exists
        """
        if not os.path.exists(self.folder):
            os.mkdir(self.folder)
        else:
            raise FileExistsError("[*] Already Exists This Folder")

    def login(self):
        """Login To Instagram"""
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login")
        time.sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)
        submit = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('form')
        submit.submit()
        time.sleep(3)

        """Check For Invalid Credentials"""
        try:
            var_error = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("eiCW-").text
            raise ValueError("[!] Invalid Credentials")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try:
            """Close Notifications"""
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]').click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        """Taking cookies"""
        cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()
        for cookie in cookies:
            c = {cookie["name"]: cookie["value"]}
            self.http_base.cookies.update(c)

        """Check for availability"""
        self.check_availability()
        self.driver.get(self.url.format(name=self.name))
        return self.scroll_down()

    def _get_href(self):
        elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
        for elem in elements:
            urls = elem.get_attribute("href")
            if "p" in urls.split("/"):
                self.links.append(urls)

    def scroll_down(self):
        """Taking hrefs while scrolling down"""
        end_scroll = []
        while True:
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(2)
            self._get_href()
            time.sleep(2)
            new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            end_scroll.append(new_height)
            if end_scroll.count(end_scroll[-1]) > 4:
                self.extraction_url()
                break

    def extraction_url(self):
        """Gathering Images and Videos Using ThreadPoolExecutor and pass to function <fetch_url> """
        links = list(set(self.links))

        print("[!] Ready for video - images".title())
        print(f"[*] extracting {len(links)} posts , please wait...".title())

        new_links = [urllib.parse.urljoin(link, "?__a=1") for link in links]
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
            [executor.submit(self.fetch_url, link) for link in new_links]

    def fetch_url(self, url):
        """
        This function extracts images and videos
        :param url: Taking the url
        """
        logging_page_id = self.http_base.get(url.split()[0]).json()
        try:
            """Taking Gallery Photos or Videos"""
            for log_pages in logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_sidecar_to_children']['edges']:
                video = log_pages["node"]["is_video"]
                if video:
                    video_url = log_pages["node"]["video_url"]
                    self.videos.append(video_url)
                else:
                    image = log_pages["node"]["display_url"]
                    self.pictures.append(image)

        except KeyError:
            """Unique photo or Video"""
            image = logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['display_url']
            self.pictures.append(image)

            if logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']["is_video"]:
                videos = logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']["video_url"]
                self.videos.append(videos)

    def download_video(self, new_videos):
        """
        Saving the content of video in the file
        """
        number = new_videos[0]
        link = new_videos[1]
        with open(os.path.join(self.folder, f"Video{number}.mp4"), "wb") as f:
            content_of_video = InstagramPV.content_of_url(link, self.http_base)
            f.write(content_of_video)

    def images_download(self, new_pictures):
        """Saving the content of picture in the file"""
        number = new_pictures[0]
        link = new_pictures[1]
        with open(os.path.join(self.folder, f"Image{number}.jpg"), "wb") as f:
            content_of_picture = InstagramPV.content_of_url(link, self.http_base)
            f.write(content_of_picture)

    def downloading_video_images(self):
        """Using multiprocessing for Saving Images and Videos"""
        print("[*] ready for saving images and videos!".title())
        picture_data = enumerate(list(set(self.pictures)))
        video_data = enumerate(list(set(self.videos)))
        pool = Pool(8)
        pool.map(self.images_download, picture_data)
        pool.map(self.download_video, video_data)
        print("[+] Done")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.http_base.close()
        self.driver.close()

    @staticmethod
    def content_of_url(url, req):
        data = req.get(url)
        return data.content


def main():
    USERNAME = ""
    PASSWORD = ""
    NAME = ""
    FOLDER = ""
    with InstagramPV(USERNAME, PASSWORD, FOLDER, NAME) as pv:
        pv.control()
        pv.login()
        pv.downloading_video_images()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Second approach

```
chromedriver_path = None


class PrivateException(Exception):
    pass


class InstagramData:

    def __init__(self, search_name):
        """
        :param search_name: The Profile that will search
        """
        self._search_name = search_name
        self.links = []
        self.videos = []
        self.pictures = []

    @property
    def name(self):
        """To avoid any errors, with regex find the url and taking the name <search_name>"""
        find_name = "".join(re.findall(r"(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", self._search_name))
        if find_name.startswith("https"):
            self._search_name = urllib.parse.urlparse(find_name).path.split("/")[1]
            return self._search_name
        else:
            return self._search_name

    @classmethod
    def check_availability(cls, session, url):
        """
        Check availability of the profile If its private and status code
        :param session: session  <self.http_base> requests.session
        :param url: the url
        :return:
        """
        search = session.get(url, params={"__a": 1})
        search.raise_for_status()

        load_and_check = search.json()
        privacy = load_and_check.get("graphql").get("user").get("is_private")
        followed_by_viewer = load_and_check.get("graphql").get("user").get("followed_by_viewer")
        if privacy and not followed_by_viewer:
            raise PrivateException("[!] Account is private")

    @classmethod
    def login_and_scrape(cls, username, password, session, url):
        """
        Login tO instagram, checking availability and taking links
        :param username: the username
        :param password: the password
        :param session: session <self.http_base> requests.session
        :param url: The URL
        :return: The links that we collect from scroll down
        """
        if chromedriver_path is not None:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
        else:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login")
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
        submit = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('form')
        submit.submit()
        time.sleep(8)

        """Check For Invalid Credentials"""
        try:
            var_error = driver.find_element_by_class_name("eiCW-").text
            raise ValueError("[!] Invalid Credentials")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try:
            """Close Notifications"""
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]').click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        """Getting cookies and pass it to session parameter"""
        cookies = driver.get_cookies()
        for cookie in cookies:
            c = {cookie["name"]: cookie["value"]}
            session.cookies.update(c)

        """Checking the availability"""
        InstagramData.check_availability(session, url)

        driver.get(url)

        """Scrolling down and taking the href"""
        new_links = []
        end_scroll = []
        while True:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(2)
            for href in cls.get_href(driver):
                new_links.append(href)
            time.sleep(2)
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            end_scroll.append(new_height)
            if end_scroll.count(end_scroll[-1]) > 4:
                driver.close()
                return new_links

    @staticmethod
    def get_href(driver):
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
        for elem in elements:
            urls = elem.get_attribute("href")
            if "p" in urls.split("/"):
                yield urls

    def fetch_url(self, session, url):
        """
        Collect the images, videos and appending on self.pictures, self.videos
        :param session: Session of <self.http_base>
        :param url: url
        :return:
        """

        logging_page_id = session.get(url.split()[0]).json()
        try:
            """Taking Gallery Photos or Videos"""
            for log_pages in logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_sidecar_to_children']['edges']:
                video = log_pages["node"]["is_video"]
                if video:
                    video_url = log_pages["node"]["video_url"]
                    self.videos.append(video_url)
                else:
                    image = log_pages["node"]["display_url"]
                    self.pictures.append(image)

        except KeyError:
            """Unique photo or Video"""
            image = logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['display_url']
            self.pictures.append(image)

            if logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']["is_video"]:
                video = logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']["video_url"]
                self.videos.append(video)


class InstagramPV(InstagramData):
    def __init__(self, username, password, search_name, folder):
        super(InstagramPV, self).__init__(search_name)
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.folder = folder
        self.http_base = requests.Session()
        self.url = "https://www.instagram.com/{name}/"

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def control(self):
        """
        Create the folder name and raises an error if already exists
        """
        if not os.path.exists(self.folder):
            os.mkdir(self.folder)
        else:
            raise FileExistsError("[*] Already Exists This Folder")

    def extraction_url(self):
        """Gathering Images and Videos Using ThreadPoolExecutor """
        links = list(
            set(InstagramData.login_and_scrape(self.username, self.password, self.http_base,
                                               self.url.format(name=self.name))))

        print("[!] Ready for video - images".title())
        print(f"[*] extracting {len(links)} posts , please wait...".title())

        new_links = [urllib.parse.urljoin(link, "?__a=1") for link in links]
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
            [executor.submit(self.fetch_url(self.http_base, link)) for link in new_links]

    def download_video(self, new_videos):
        """
        Saving the content of video in the file
        """
        number = new_videos[0]
        link = new_videos[1]
        with open(os.path.join(self.folder, f"Video{number}.mp4"), "wb") as f:
            content_of_video = InstagramPV.content_of_url(link, self.http_base)
            f.write(content_of_video)

    def images_download(self, new_pictures):
        """Saving the content of picture in the file"""
        number = new_pictures[0]
        link = new_pictures[1]
        with open(os.path.join(self.folder, f"Image{number}.jpg"), "wb") as f:
            content_of_picture = InstagramPV.content_of_url(link, self.http_base)
            f.write(content_of_picture)

    def downloading_video_images(self):
        self.control()
        self.extraction_url()
        """Using multiprocessing for Saving Images and Videos"""
        print("[*] ready for saving images and videos!".title())
        picture_data = enumerate(list(set(self.pictures)))
        video_data = enumerate(list(set(self.videos)))
        pool = Pool(8)
        pool.map(self.images_download, picture_data)
        pool.map(self.download_video, video_data)
        print("[+] Done")

    @staticmethod
    def content_of_url(url, req):
        data = req.get(url)
        return data.content

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.http_base.close()


def main():
    USERNAME = ""
    PASSWORD = ""
    NAME = ""
    FOLDER = ""
    with InstagramPV(USERNAME, PASSWORD, NAME, FOLDER) as pv:
        pv.downloading_video_images()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My previous posts:

1. [Instagram scraper Posts (Videos and Photos)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238713/instagram-scraper-posts-videos-and-photos])
2. [Scraping Instagram with selenium, extract URLs, download posts](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238902/scraping-instagram-with-selenium-extract-urls-download-posts)
3. [Web scraping using selenium, multiprocessing, InstagramBot](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238969/web-scraping-using-selenium-multiprocessing-instagrambot)

Comment: I realize that your earlier posts probably contain this, but a short paragraph on what the code does might be helpful. You might also want to delete one of the tags and add the comparative review tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Type hints

```
def __init__(self, username, password, folder, search_name):
```

can (probably) be

```
def __init__(self, username: str, password: str, folder: Path, search_name: str):
```

Also, since these lists are initialized without a direct reference to the args, they should be type-declared:

```
    self.links: List[str] = []
    self.pictures: List[str] = []
    self.videos: List[str] = []
```

### Paths

Note that I suggest the use of `Path`. Read about it here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Then later on, you can use it like so:

```
    self.folder.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
```

One line, no existence checks necessary. Also, this:

```
os.path.join(self.folder, f"Image{number}.jpg"
```

can be easier:

```
self.folder / f'Image{number}.jpg'
```

### Combined cookie update

I think that

```
    """Taking cookies"""
    cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()
    for cookie in cookies:
        c = {cookie["name"]: cookie["value"]}
        self.http_base.cookies.update(c)
```

can be

```
# Taking cookies
cookies = {
   cookie['name']: cookie['value']
   for cookie in self.driver.get_cookies()
}
self.http_base.cookies.update(cookies)
```

### Quote style

... is inconsistent in places like this:

```
        if logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']["is_video"]:
```

So pick one or the other and stick with it.

### Use a generator

`scroll_down` can become a generator and gain some efficiency:

- Use a `Counter` class instance rather than calling `end_scroll.count()`, which is quite inefficient.
- Do not maintain an `end_scroll` list. Rather than appending, `yield new_height`, which makes the function a generator.

### Nomenclature

`extraction_url` sounds like a noun (i.e. it gets some data for you). That's not actually what it does. Instead, it seems like it submits some links. Call it `submit` or `submit_links` (this is a verb, and makes it clear that it's an "action", not a "getter").

### Magic numbers

In this:

```
if end_scroll.count(end_scroll[-1]) > 4:
```

What is 4? This should be saved to a named constant.

Comment: I have two questions. 1) Can i use type hints for every function in the class? 2) In quote style , you mean to put in variable?

Comment: _Can i use type hints for every function in the class?_ - Yes, you should :)

Comment: _In quote style , you mean to put in variable?_ No, as in choose single or double quotes only.

Comment: For the function `scroll_down` i didn't make it a generator, instead i tested the expression (condition) the number of posts and the `self.links`. Should i make it a generator anyway?

Comment: my new [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239539/instagram-scraping-using-selenium) :)