# Instagram Scraping Using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium

Python script that can download images and videos of the user, like Gallery with photos or videos. It saves the data in the folder.

## How it works:

- Log in in instragram using selenium and navigate to the profile
- Check the availability of Instagram profile if it's private or existing
- Gathering urls from images or videos
- Using threads and multiprocessing improve execution speed

My code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import urllib.parse
import re
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from typing import *

chromedriver_path = None


class PrivateException(Exception):
    pass


class InstagramPV:

    def __init__(self, username: str, password: str, folder: Path, search_name: str):
        """

        :param username: username
        :param password: password
        :param folder: folder name
        :param search_name: the name what will search
        """
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.folder = folder
        self.http_base = requests.Session()
        self._search_name = search_name
        self.links: List[str] = []
        self.pictures: List[str] = []
        self.videos: List[str] = []
        self.url: str = 'https://www.instagram.com/{name}/'
        self.posts: int = 0
        if chromedriver_path is not None:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
        else:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        """
        To avoid any errors, with regex find the url and taking the name <search_name>
        :return: The name of the Profile
        """
        find_name = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)', self._search_name))
        if find_name.startswith('https'):
            self._search_name = urllib.parse.urlparse(find_name).path.split('/')[1]
            return self._search_name
        else:
            return self._search_name

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def check_availability(self) -> None:
        """
        Checking Status code, Taking number of posts, Privacy and followed by viewer
        Raise Error if the Profile is private and not following by viewer
        :return: None
        """
        search = self.http_base.get(self.url.format(name=self.name), params={'__a': 1})
        search.raise_for_status()

        load_and_check = search.json()
        self.posts = load_and_check.get('graphql').get('user').get('edge_owner_to_timeline_media').get('count')
        privacy = load_and_check.get('graphql').get('user').get('is_private')
        followed_by_viewer = load_and_check.get('graphql').get('user').get('followed_by_viewer')
        if privacy and not followed_by_viewer:
            raise PrivateException('[!] Account is private')

    def control(self) -> None:
        """
        Create the folder name
        """
        self.folder.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    def login(self) -> None:
        """Login To Instagram"""
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'form')))
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)
        submit = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('form')
        submit.submit()

        """Check For Invalid Credentials"""
        try:
            var_error = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('eiCW-').text
            raise ValueError('[!] Invalid Credentials')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try:
            """Close Notifications"""
            notifications = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Not Now"]')))
            notifications.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        """Taking cookies"""
        cookies = {
            cookie['name']: cookie['value']
            for cookie in self.driver.get_cookies()
        }

        self.http_base.cookies.update(cookies)

        """Check for availability"""
        self.check_availability()

        self.driver.get(self.url.format(name=self.name))

        return self.scroll_down()

    def get_href(self) -> None:
        elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href]')
        for elem in elements:
            urls = elem.get_attribute('href')
            if 'p' in urls.split('/'):
                self.links.append(urls)

    def scroll_down(self) -> None:
        """Taking hrefs while scrolling down"""
        while len(list(set(self.links))) < self.posts:
            self.get_href()
            time.sleep(1)
            self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
            time.sleep(1)
        return self.submit_links()

    def submit_links(self) -> None:
        """Gathering Images and Videos and pass to function <fetch_url> Using ThreadPoolExecutor"""
        self.control()
        links = list(set(self.links))

        print('[!] Ready for video - images'.title())
        print(f'[*] extracting {len(links)} posts , please wait...'.title())

        new_links = [urllib.parse.urljoin(link, '?__a=1') for link in links]
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
            [executor.submit(self.fetch_url, link) for link in new_links]

    def fetch_url(self, url: str) -> None:
        """
        This function extracts images and videos
        :param url: Taking the url
        :return None
        """

        logging_page_id = self.http_base.get(url.split()[0]).json()
        try:
            """Taking Gallery Photos or Videos"""
            for log_pages in logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_sidecar_to_children']['edges']:
                video = log_pages['node']['is_video']
                if video:
                    video_url = log_pages['node']['video_url']
                    self.videos.append(video_url)
                else:
                    image = log_pages['node']['display_url']
                    self.pictures.append(image)

        except KeyError:
            """Unique photo or Video"""
            image = logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['display_url']
            self.pictures.append(image)

            if logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['is_video']:
                videos = logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['video_url']
                self.videos.append(videos)

    def download_video(self, new_videos: Tuple[int, str]) -> None:
        """
        Saving the video content
        :param new_videos: Tuple[int,str]
        :return: None
        """
        number = new_videos[0]
        link = new_videos[1]
        with open(self.folder / f'Video{number}.mp4', 'wb') as f:
            content_of_video = InstagramPV.content_of_url(self.http_base.get(link))
            f.write(content_of_video)

    def images_download(self, new_pictures: Tuple[int, str]) -> None:
        """
        Saving the picture content
        :param new_pictures: Tuple[int, str]
        :return: None
        """
        number = new_pictures[0]
        link = new_pictures[1]
        with open(self.folder / f'Image{number}.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            content_of_picture = InstagramPV.content_of_url(self.http_base.get(link))
            f.write(content_of_picture)

    def downloading_video_images(self) -> None:
        """Using multiprocessing for Saving Images and Videos"""
        print('[*] ready for saving images and videos!'.title())
        picture_data = enumerate(list(set(self.pictures)))
        video_data = enumerate(list(set(self.videos)))
        pool = Pool(8)
        pool.map(self.images_download, picture_data)
        pool.map(self.download_video, video_data)
        print('[+] Done')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.http_base.close()
        self.driver.close()

    @staticmethod
    def content_of_url(req: [requests.sessions.Session, requests.models.Response]) -> bytes:
        """
        :param req:  requests.sessions.Session, requests.models.Response
        :return: Content of Url
        """
        return req.content


def main():
    USERNAME = ''
    PASSWORD = ''
    NAME = ''
    FOLDER = Path('')
    with InstagramPV(USERNAME, PASSWORD, FOLDER, NAME) as pv:
        pv.login()
        pv.downloading_video_images()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My previous comparative review tag:
[Instagram Bot, selenium, web scraping](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239074/instagram-bot-selenium-web-scraping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Duplicated statements in an if-block

```
    if find_name.startswith('https'):
        self._search_name = urllib.parse.urlparse(find_name).path.split('/')[1]
        return self._search_name
    else:
        return self._search_name
```

should just be

```
    if find_name.startswith('https'):
        self._search_name = urllib.parse.urlparse(find_name).path.split('/')[1]
    return self._search_name
```

### Type hint difference

You say this has no return:

```
def login(self) -> None:
```

But then you do one anyway?

```
    return self.scroll_down()
```

This is repeated in `scroll_down()` itself.

### List comprehensions as loops

I find this:

```
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        [executor.submit(self.fetch_url, link) for link in new_links]
```

to be unnecessary. It's more legible to have a simple `for`-loop than to construct a list and throw it away.

### Method order

For sane legibility, it's better to put `__exit__` directly after `__enter__` in the class.

### `content_of_url`

This method:

```
@staticmethod
def content_of_url(req: [requests.sessions.Session, requests.models.Response]) -> bytes:
    """
    :param req:  requests.sessions.Session, requests.models.Response
    :return: Content of Url
    """
    return req.content
```

doesn't do anything useful enough to deserve being a dedicated method. Even if it did, the type hint for `req` seems wrong; it should just be a `Response`. I'm not sure why the `Session` is mentioned.

### Local variables

```
USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''
NAME = ''
FOLDER = Path('')
```

should be lowercase, now that they're in function scope.

Comment: Thanks!! About the type hints, should just get rid of _return_ or it's returning something that i didnt notice? Also, in The content_of_url, if i dont mention the _Session_ is raising me a warning. Should i put it in the class too or to do something else?

Comment: _ should just get rid of return_ - yes, since the bottom of that stack does not return anything. _if i dont mention the Session is raising me a warning_ - what warning?

Comment: Strange. It was raising me a warning at _self.http_base.get(link)_ but now nothing. I dont understand. Its ok now

Comment: Should i post my next question ?

Comment: Since you've accepted an answer on this one, I would say yes.

Comment: Finally my new [questtion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239940/instagram-scraping-posts-using-selenium) :)