# Instagram Scraping Posts Using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium, instagram

Python script that can download images and videos of the user, like Gallery with photos or videos. It saves the data in the folder.

How it works:

- Log in in instragram using selenium and navigate to the profile
- Check the availability of Instagram profile if it's private or existing
- Gathering urls from images or videos
- Using threads and multiprocessing improve execution speed

Usage:

`myfile.py -u example@hotmail.com -p mypassword -f myfile -n stackoverjoke`

My code:

```
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import urllib.parse
import re
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from typing import *
import argparse

chromedriver_path = None


class PrivateException(Exception):
    pass


class InstagramPV:

    def __init__(self, username: str, password: str, folder: Path, search_name: str):
        """

        :param username: username
        :param password: password
        :param folder: folder name
        :param search_name: the name what will search
        """
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.folder = folder
        self.http_base = requests.Session()
        self._search_name = search_name
        self.links: List[str] = []
        self.pictures: List[str] = []
        self.videos: List[str] = []
        self.url: str = 'https://www.instagram.com/{name}/'
        if chromedriver_path is not None:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
        else:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        """
        To avoid any errors, with regex find the url and taking the name <search_name>
        :return: The name of the Profile
        """
        find_name = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)', self._search_name))
        if find_name.startswith('https'):
            self._search_name = urllib.parse.urlparse(find_name).path.split('/')[1]
        return self._search_name

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.http_base.close()
        self.driver.close()

    def check_availability(self) -> None:
        """
        Checking Status code, Taking number of posts, Privacy and followed by viewer
        Raise Error if the Profile is private and not following by viewer
        :return: None
        """
        search = self.http_base.get(self.url.format(name=self.name), params={'__a': 1})
        search.raise_for_status()

        load_and_check = search.json()
        privacy = load_and_check.get('graphql').get('user').get('is_private')
        followed_by_viewer = load_and_check.get('graphql').get('user').get('followed_by_viewer')
        if privacy and not followed_by_viewer:
            raise PrivateException('[!] Account is private')

    def control(self) -> None:
        """
        Create the folder name
        """
        self.folder.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    def login(self) -> None:
        """Login To Instagram"""
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'form')))
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)
        submit = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('form')
        submit.submit()

        """Check For Invalid Credentials"""
        try:
            var_error = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('eiCW-').text
            raise ValueError('[!] Invalid Credentials')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try:
            """Close Notifications"""
            notifications = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Not Now"]')))
            notifications.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        """Taking cookies"""
        cookies = {
            cookie['name']: cookie['value']
            for cookie in self.driver.get_cookies()
        }

        self.http_base.cookies.update(cookies)

        """Check for availability"""
        self.check_availability()

        self.driver.get(self.url.format(name=self.name))

        self.submit_links()

    def get_href(self) -> None:
        elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href]')
        for elem in elements:
            urls = elem.get_attribute('href')
            if 'p' in urls.split('/'):
                self.links.append(urls)

    def located(self) -> bool:
        """
        Become a flag. While this element is displayed keep scrolling down until it isn't
        :return: True if the element is displayed, False if it isn't
        """
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_4emnV"]').is_displayed()
            return True
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False

    def scroll_down(self) -> Iterable[bool]:
        '''Taking hrefs while scrolling down'''
        while True:
            flag = self.located()
            self.get_href()
            time.sleep(1)
            self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
            time.sleep(1)
            yield flag

    def submit_links(self) -> None:
        """Gathering Images and Videos and pass to function <fetch_url> Using ThreadPoolExecutor"""

        for displayed_more in self.scroll_down():
            if not displayed_more:
                break

        self.control()

        seen = set()
        links = [link for link in self.links if not (link in seen or seen.add(link))]

        print('[!] Ready for video - images'.title())
        print(f'[*] extracting {len(links)} posts , please wait...'.title())

        new_links = [urllib.parse.urljoin(link, '?__a=1') for link in links]
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
            for link in new_links:
                executor.submit(self.fetch_url, link)

    def fetch_url(self, url: str) -> None:
        """
        This function extracts images and videos
        :param url: Taking the url
        :return None
        """

        logging_page_id = self.http_base.get(url.split()[0]).json()
        try:
            """Taking Gallery Photos or Videos"""
            for log_pages in logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_sidecar_to_children']['edges']:
                video = log_pages['node']['is_video']
                if video:
                    video_url = log_pages['node']['video_url']
                    self.videos.append(video_url)
                else:
                    image = log_pages['node']['display_url']
                    self.pictures.append(image)

        except KeyError:
            """Unique photo or Video"""
            image = logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['display_url']
            self.pictures.append(image)

            if logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['is_video']:
                videos = logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']['video_url']
                self.videos.append(videos)

    def download_video(self, new_videos: Tuple[int, str]) -> None:
        """
        Saving the video content
        :param new_videos: Tuple[int,str]
        :return: None
        """
        number = new_videos[0]
        link = new_videos[1]
        with open(self.folder / f'Video{number}.mp4', 'wb') as f:
            content_of_video = self.http_base.get(link).content
            f.write(content_of_video)

    def images_download(self, new_pictures: Tuple[int, str]) -> None:
        """
        Saving the picture content
        :param new_pictures: Tuple[int, str]
        :return: None
        """

        number = new_pictures[0]
        link = new_pictures[1]
        with open(self.folder / f'Image{number}.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            content_of_picture = self.http_base.get(link).content
            f.write(content_of_picture)

    def downloading_video_images(self) -> None:
        """Using multiprocessing for Saving Images and Videos"""
        print('[*] ready for saving images and videos!'.title())
        picture_data = enumerate(list(set(self.pictures)))
        video_data = enumerate(list(set(self.videos)))
        pool = Pool(8)
        pool.map(self.images_download, picture_data)
        pool.map(self.download_video, video_data)
        print('[+] Done')


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', help='Username or your email of your account', action='store',
                        required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', help='Password of your account', action='store', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--filename', help='Filename for storing data', action='store', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--name', help='Name to search or link', action='store', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    with InstagramPV(args.username, args.password, Path(args.filename), args.name) as pv:
        pv.login()
        pv.downloading_video_images()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Changes:

1) I changed the behaviour of the function `scroll_down` - avoiding "bugs" of instagram

2) Added function `located`

My previous comparative review tag: [Instagram Scraping Using Selenium](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239539/instagram-scraping-using-selenium/239542?noredirect=1#comment470188_239542)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Global constants

`chromedriver_path` should be capitalized. Otherwise: I assume that you manually change it from `None` to some meaningful value for your local system. Try not to do this - instead, accept that path as an environmental variable, in a config file, or as a command-line parameter.

### Captain Obvious

This:

```
    """
    :param username: username
    :param password: password
    :param folder: folder name
    """
```

is worse than having no comments at all. Fill these out to be meaningful to someone who doesn't know what your script does.

### Side-effects

One would expect, looking from the outside, that `name` simply returns a string - especially since it's marked as a property. It does that, but it also has the side-effect of setting `self._search_name` (sometimes). There are at least two problems with this:

- State modification in a getter - this is occasionally useful, i.e. in caching, but that isn't what you're doing here
- Conditional state modification whose reason isn't obvious - why is it that a member is only set if the URL is HTTPS?

### Names

`control` doesn't seem to control anything; it creates a directory.

`get_href` is not a getter; it doesn't return anything. It actually *would* make more sense as a static getter that `yield`s instead of appending to a list; then the caller could simply `self.links.extend(self.get_hrefs())`.

### `located`

In its current implementation, this makes no sense:

```
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_4emnV"]').is_displayed()
        return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
```

You call `is_displayed` and throw its return value away, relying on a no-such-element to determine the return value of your function. Why call `is_displayed` at all?

### `scroll_down`

You have a `while True` that doesn't exit on its own. Instead, the outer caller waits for a boolean:

```
    for displayed_more in self.scroll_down():
        if not displayed_more:
            break
```

This entire iterable structure all the way up to `get_href` needs to be re-thought. What you should have is a generator function that, instead of yielding a `bool` to terminate, yields a URL string, and breaks out of the loop (with a `break`, not a boolean flag) when the no-such-element condition is met.

### Side-effects in comprehensions

This is particularly gruesome:

```
    seen = set()
    links = [link for link in self.links if not (link in seen or seen.add(link))]
```

As soon as you have a term of a statement that's being relied upon to modify the iteration, you should expand this out into a normal loop. However, if I understand this correctly, you're simply removing dupes, in which case

```
links = set(self.links)
```

If you care deeply about order, then there are other ways to do this that still don't require a custom generator.

### Generator materialization

This:

```
    new_links = [urllib.parse.urljoin(link, '?__a=1') for link in links]
```

should use parentheses instead of brackets, because you don't need the list in memory - you only need the generator once through.

### Variable reuse

Save

```
logging_page_id['graphql']['shortcode_media']
```

to a temporary variable for reuse.

### Tuples in a function

This:

```
def download_video(self, new_videos: Tuple[int, str]) -> None:
```

can simplify its tuple unpacking from

```
    number = new_videos[0]
    link = new_videos[1]
```

to

```
number, link = new_videos
```

### Magic numbers

Pull the 8 from this

```
Pool(8)
```

into a constant, for instance

```
N_PROCESSES = 8
# ...
Pool(N_PROCESSES)
```

This is more maintainable and self-documenting.

Comment: I have tons of questions but i will ask the most "important" for me. 1) In _name_ you mean to check everything even the URL isn't HTTPS? Should i get rid of property and try something else, because my intention is to extract the name and do the rest. 2) In scroll_down i fell into an infinity loop and i don't know if this is an instagram bug, but i saw "wrong" number of posts while the real posts were less. So, i wanted to find something to stop this, like the end of page. I think that the problem comes from scrolling down.

Comment: 3) In _Side-effects in comprehensions_ i tried to remove the duplicate links without changing the order. Otherwise i could use _collections.OrderedDict_ 3) In _Tuples in a function_ in the previous post you mention _You're better off accepting number and link as separate arguments._ . 4) Magic numbers? I didn't undertand. Sorry for asking so many things but i am learning from your answers.

Comment: _check everything even the URL isn't HTTPS?_ - I don't know. What was your original motivation for only parsing HTTPS URLs?

Comment: _i wanted to find something to stop this_ - I think ending the loop on missing-element is fine, but you shouldn't be using booleans to do this.

Comment: _use collections.OrderedDict_ - Yes, this is what you should do.

Comment: _you mention You're better off accepting number and link as separate arguments_ - that's true, but I think it isn't possible given your usage of `map()`. You passing in a tuple is probably fine, but there's an easier way to unpack it.

Comment: _Magic numbers? I didn't undertand_ - edited for context

Comment: May i ask why using booleans to stop is wrong way? When and which cases we can use booleans. You mean is too much when i could use simplest way? Also, i want to understand the point of view of "gruesome" . Thanks!

Comment: _i want to understand the point of view of "gruesome"_ - Apologies; that's colloquial and not technical. Basically, it's not a good idea to mutate a set on the inside of a list comprehension.

Comment: _May i ask why using booleans to stop is wrong way?_ - Instead of looping, yielding a flag, outer looping and listening to the flag, yielding the data you actually care about, which is simpler.

Comment: I think i improved my code. By the way i learned so much these weeks that i didn't learned for months! Thanks to you! my [new question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240182/download-pictures-or-videos-from-instagram-using-selenium)