# Scraping Instagram - Download posts, photos - videos

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium, instagram

Python script that can downloads public and private profiles images and videos, like Gallery with photos or videos. It saves the data in the folder.

How it works:

- Log in in instragram using selenium and navigate to the profile
- Checking the availability of Instagram profile if it's private or existing
- Creates a folder with the name of your choice
- Gathering urls from images and videos
- Using threads and multiprocessing improving the execution speed

My code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from typing import *
import argparse
import shutil


class PrivateException(Exception):
    pass


class InstagramPV:
    MAX_WORKERS: int = 8
    N_PROCESSES: int = 8

    def __init__(self, username: str, password: str, folder: Path, profile_name: str):
        """

        :param username: Username or E-mail for Log-in in Instagram
        :param password: Password for Log-in in Instagram
        :param folder: Folder name that will save the posts
        :param profile_name: The profile name that will search
        """
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.folder = folder
        self.http_base = requests.Session()
        self.profile_name = profile_name
        self.links: List[str] = []
        self.pictures: List[str] = []
        self.videos: List[str] = []
        self.url: str = 'https://www.instagram.com/{name}/'
        self.posts: int = 0
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.http_base.close()
        self.driver.close()

    def check_availability(self) -> None:
        """
        Checking Status code, Taking number of posts, Privacy and followed by viewer
        Raise Error if the Profile is private and not following by viewer
        :return: None
        """
        search = self.http_base.get(self.url.format(name=self.profile_name), params={'__a': 1})
        search.raise_for_status()

        load_and_check = search.json()
        self.posts = load_and_check.get('graphql').get('user').get('edge_owner_to_timeline_media').get('count')
        privacy = load_and_check.get('graphql').get('user').get('is_private')
        followed_by_viewer = load_and_check.get('graphql').get('user').get('followed_by_viewer')
        if privacy and not followed_by_viewer:
            raise PrivateException('[!] Account is private')

    def create_folder(self) -> None:
        """Create the folder name"""
        self.folder.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    def login(self) -> None:
        """Login To Instagram"""
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'form')))
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)
        submit = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('form')
        submit.submit()

        """Check For Invalid Credentials"""
        try:
            var_error = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'eiCW-')))
            raise ValueError(var_error.text)
        except TimeoutException:
            pass

        try:
            """Close Notifications"""
            notifications = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Not Now"]')))
            notifications.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        """Taking cookies"""
        cookies = {
            cookie['name']: cookie['value']
            for cookie in self.driver.get_cookies()
        }

        self.http_base.cookies.update(cookies)

        """Check for availability"""
        self.check_availability()

        self.driver.get(self.url.format(name=self.profile_name))

        self.scroll_down()

    def posts_urls(self) -> None:
        """Taking the URLs from posts and appending in self.links"""
        elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href]')
        for elem in elements:
            urls = elem.get_attribute('href')
            if urls not in self.links and 'p' in urls.split('/'):
                self.links.append(urls)

    def scroll_down(self) -> None:
        """Scrolling down the page and taking the URLs"""
        last_height = self.driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
        while True:
            self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
            time.sleep(1)
            self.posts_urls()
            time.sleep(1)
            new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            if new_height == last_height:
                break
            last_height = new_height
        self.submit_links()

    def submit_links(self) -> None:
        """Gathering Images and Videos and pass to function <fetch_url> Using ThreadPoolExecutor"""

        self.create_folder()

        print('[!] Ready for video - images'.title())
        print(f'[*] extracting {len(self.links)} posts , please wait...'.title())

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
            for link in self.links:
                executor.submit(self.fetch_url, link)

    def get_fields(self, nodes: Dict, *keys) -> Any:
        """
        :param nodes: The json data from the link using only the first two keys 'graphql' and 'shortcode_media'
        :param keys: Keys that will be add to the nodes and will have the results of 'type' or 'URL'
        :return: The value of the key <fields>
        """
        fields = nodes['graphql']['shortcode_media']
        for key in keys:
            fields = fields[key]
        return fields

    def fetch_url(self, url: str) -> None:
        """
        This function extracts images and videos
        :param url: Taking the url
        :return None
        """

        logging_page_id = self.http_base.get(url, params={'__a': 1}).json()
        if self.get_fields(logging_page_id, '__typename') == 'GraphImage':
            image_url = self.get_fields(logging_page_id, 'display_url')
            self.pictures.append(image_url)

        elif self.get_fields(logging_page_id, '__typename') == 'GraphVideo':
            video_url = self.get_fields(logging_page_id, 'video_url')
            self.videos.append(video_url)

        elif self.get_fields(logging_page_id, '__typename') == 'GraphSidecar':
            for sidecar in self.get_fields(logging_page_id, 'edge_sidecar_to_children', 'edges'):
                if sidecar['node']['__typename'] == 'GraphImage':
                    image_url = sidecar['node']['display_url']
                    self.pictures.append(image_url)
                else:
                    video_url = sidecar['node']['video_url']
                    self.videos.append(video_url)
        else:
            print(f'Warning {url}: has unknown type of {self.get_fields(logging_page_id,"__typename")}')

    def download_video(self, new_videos: Tuple[int, str]) -> None:
        """
        Saving the video content
        :param new_videos: Tuple[int,str]
        :return: None
        """
        number, link = new_videos

        with open(self.folder / f'Video{number}.mp4', 'wb') as f:
            content_of_video = self.http_base.get(link, stream=True).raw
            shutil.copyfileobj(content_of_video, f)

    def images_download(self, new_pictures: Tuple[int, str]) -> None:
        """
        Saving the picture content
        :param new_pictures: Tuple[int, str]
        :return: None
        """

        number, link = new_pictures
        with open(self.folder / f'Image{number}.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            content_of_picture = self.http_base.get(link, stream=True).raw
            shutil.copyfileobj(content_of_picture, f)

    def downloading_video_images(self) -> None:
        """Using multiprocessing for Saving Images and Videos"""
        print('[*] ready for saving images and videos!'.title())
        picture_data = enumerate(self.pictures)
        video_data = enumerate(self.videos)
        pool = Pool(self.N_PROCESSES)
        pool.map(self.images_download, picture_data)
        pool.map(self.download_video, video_data)
        print('[+] Done')


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-U', '--username', help='Username or your email of your account', action='store',
                        required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-P', '--password', help='Password of your account', action='store', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-F', '--filename', help='Filename for storing data', action='store', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-T', '--target', help='Profile name to search', action='store', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with InstagramPV(args.username, args.password, Path(args.filename), args.target) as pv:
        pv.login()
        pv.downloading_video_images()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Usage: `myfile.py -U myemail@hotmail.com -P mypassword -F Mynamefile -T stackoverjoke`

My previous comparative review tag:[Download pictures (or videos) from Instagram using Selenium](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240182/download-pictures-or-videos-from-instagram-using-selenium/240183#240183)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### More constants

This:

```
    self.url: str = 'https://www.instagram.com/{name}/'
```

appears to be a constant, so it can join the others in class scope. While you're doing that, you can also pull the URL from `self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')` into a constant; and also pull the base URL out. In other words:

```
class InstagramPV:
    MAX_WORKERS: int = 8
    N_PROCESSES: int = 8

    BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
    PROFILE_URL_FMT = BASE_URL + '{name}/'
    LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL + 'accounts/login'
```

### Nested `get`

These:

```
load_and_check.get('graphql').get('user').get('edge_owner_to_timeline_media').get('count')
```

won't actually do what you want, which is a fail-safe object traversal. For that you need to provide defaults that are empty dictionaries:

```
self.posts = (
    load_and_check.get('graphql', {})
    .get('user', {})
    .get('edge_owner_to_timeline_media', {})
    .get('count')
)
```

Also, the first part should be factored out into its own temporary variable, since it's used three times:

```
user = (
    load_and_check.get('graphql', {})
    .get('user', {})
)
```

### Methods for reuse

```
self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

should be factored out into a new method for re-use.

### Static function

This:

```
def get_fields(self, nodes: Dict, *keys) -> Any:
    """
    :param nodes: The json data from the link using only the first two keys 'graphql' and 'shortcode_media'
    :param keys: Keys that will be add to the nodes and will have the results of 'type' or 'URL'
    :return: The value of the key <fields>
    """
    fields = nodes['graphql']['shortcode_media']
    for key in keys:
        fields = fields[key]
    return fields
```

doesn't ever use `self`, which is a big clue that it doesn't belong as an instance method. You should just make it a `@staticmethod`. The only reason I don't recommend it moving to global scope is that it still has knowledge of the Instagram data format, with its reference to `graphql`.

### Dictionary traversal

The loop in `get_fields` can be replaced with a call to `functools.reduce(dict.get, keys, media)`. Also, `keys` - even though it is a variadic argument - can still receive a type hint, and should be `Iterable[str]`. `nodes` itself, if you don't know a lot about the structure of the dictionary, can still be narrowed to `nodes: Dict[str, Any]`.

### Context manager for response

Now that you're using the streaming interface for Requests (nice!), it's more important that you use the response object as a context manager. For more information read https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4136

Basically:

```
with open(self.folder / f'Video{number}.mp4', 'wb') as f, \
     self.http_base.get(link, stream=True) as response:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, f)
```

Comment: Questions : 1) _Methods for reuse_ should i put this in a variable for reuse? 2) _Static function_ the field returns 'str' or 'list' , can Any be `Any[str,list]` ? 3) Staticmethods should be in the end of class or doesn't matter ?

Comment: 1. If it never changes, then yes, a variable is better than a method.

Comment: 2. This is a job for `Union`! If you know it may be `str` or `list`, then `Union[str, list]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106645/discussion-between-reinderien-and-peilonrayz).

Comment: I believe using `reduce` is bad advice. Around [15 years ago](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) Guido tried to drop `map`, `filter` and `reduce`. For reasons unknown to me they were only relegated to `functools`. However now-a-days the three functions are not in common use with [Google explicitly deprecating them](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#215-deprecated-language-features). I leave this as a notice for future users that the advice to use `reduce` may not be the best advice.

Comment: To summarize the reason that I will stand by this suggestion: being Pythonic is about simplicity, and this is simple; `functools` should be avoided when there is a simpler tool that does the same job, but there is not. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36584550/313768 remains (in my opinion, rightfully) an acceptable answer. In many, many other cases, `reduce` is a bad idea.

Comment: Just to be clear, why are you using the `requests` module if you have Selenium ?

Comment: I think it actually makes sense. If there's a large, gruesome, JS-heavy UI for which the easiest interaction is Selenium-style, use Selenium; if there's a decouple-able simple HTTP request necessary, Requests is a better choice. Module installation via pip is cheap, so I think the correct thing is being done here.

Comment: Using both `requests` and Selenium makes it 'obvious' to the website this is a scraping job, not just because multiple connections are being made but because the default **user agent** of `requests` is something like: `python-requests/2.23.0`. So there is a greater likelihood that you will be flagged as a **bot** and blocked. I would spoof the user agent in `requests` to make it like Selenium. Also make the request headers more or less the same.

Comment: Let's please use the chat link above ^ to discuss this

Comment: @Reinderien my new [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240798/instagram-scraping-using-selenium-download-posts-photos-videos)